# Explain why there is only one homomorphism from D6 to C5

Tags: group-theory

I have two questions that I'm struggling with:

a) Give an example of a quotient group *G/N*, where *G* is not commutative (non abelian) but *G/N* is commutative (abelian)

EDIT: **I can find a specific example of this, what I don't understand is *why* this happens**

b) Explain why there is only one homomorphism $\phi: D_6 \rightarrow C_5$

[You may want to use the fact that the image of a homomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain.]

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange, Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they: Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

An "unsophisticated" answer to (b):

We are told we can use the fact that $\phi(D_6)$ is a subgroup of $C_5$.

Now: how many subgroups does $C_5$ have, exactly? Well, the order of any subgroup of $C_5$ must divide 5, so we have 2 choices:

$|\phi(D_6)| = 5$

$|\phi(D_6)| = 1$.

If the former is true, then SOME element of $D_6$ must map to a generator of $C_5$. This means we have some $g \in D_6$ such that the order of $\phi(g)$ is $5$.

Suppose the order of $g$ is $k$. Then:

$\phi(g^k) = \phi(e) = e'$, where $e'$ is the identity of $C_5$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism:

$\phi(g^k) = (\phi(g))^k$.

This tells us $(\phi(g))^k = e'$, so $5$ must divide $k$.

It is unclear whether you intend $D_6$ to have six, or twelve elements, but in either case, it does not have any elements with order a multiple of $5$, since any element of $D_6$ must have elements of orders dividing $|D_6|$, and no multiple of five divides 6 or 12.

So it cannot BE that the image of $\phi$ is all of $C_5$. This means that $\phi(D_6)$ has only ONE element, and there is only ONE possible subgroup of $C_5$ with a single element, the trivial subgroup.

Similarly, there is only ONE possible homomorphism that maps everything to the identity of $C_5$, namely, the constant-map $\phi(g) = e'$, for all $g \in D_6$.

Imanol's answer is quite correct, by the way, but I do not know if you have covered the First Isomorphism Theorem in your course yet.

Answer (score 1):

For **a)**, *homomathematicus*'s answer is correct.

For **b)**, let $\phi:D_6 \longrightarrow C_5$ be a homomorphism.

By the First Isomorphism Theorem, $\dfrac{D_6}{\ker f} \cong f(D_6) \leq C_5$.

Since $\ker f \unlhd D_6$, we've got that $|\ker f |$ divides $|D_6|=6$. Therefore, we divide all the posibilities:

1)

If $|\ker f| = 1$, then $|f(D_6)| = 6$, which is impossible since $|C_5|=5$.

2)

If $|\ker f| = 2$, then $|f(D_6)| = 3$, but since $f(D_6) \leq C_5$, $|f(D_6)|$ should divide $|C_5| = 5$, which does not.

3)

If $|\ker f| = 3$, we reach to a contradiction just like in 2).

4)

If $|\ker f| = 6$, then $f(g)=1_{C_5}$ for any $g\in D_6$, which is the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

a) If $G=S_3$ and $N=A_3$ then $S_3/A_3$ has order 2 so is abelian but $S_3$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a)

What you need is the concept of commutators. A commutator is an element of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ where $a$ and $b$ are in $G$. The thing with commutators is that $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$   iff   $ab=ba$, you can see that quite easily. Now commutators can measure the extent to which a group fails in being abelian. If we factor out all the commutators of G, we will get an abelian group.

$G$ is abelian if $HxHy = HyHx$. This also means $Hxy=Hyx$. But there is a property of cosets that states:

$Ha=Hb$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$, thus $Hxy=Hyx$ iff   $xy(yx)^{-1} \in H$. But note that $xy(yx)^{-1}$ is equal to the commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$! So if all commutators are in $H$, $G/H$ is abelian.